# What's the design purpose behind allowing `{}` curly braces initialization that's not list initialization?

Tags: c++

*I am a beginner in C++.*

I was reading C++ Primer 5th Edition. When I was studying `vector` initialization (Chapter 3.3.1), the outcomes of two use cases of `{}` initialization surprised me. And I couldn't find a good explanation of the **purpose** of such behavior.

```cpp
vector<string> v7{10};       // v7 has ten default-initialized elements
vector<string> v8{10, "hi"}; // v8 has ten elements with value "hi"
```

My intuition is that `v7` should be a vector of **one** string literal element of `"10"`, and `v8` should be a vector of **two** string literal elements of `{"10", "hi"}`. Because in the previous chapter, the `{}` initialization is introduced as a way of list initialization. So my human brain subconsciously regarded `{}` initialization as list initialization -- and, at least apparently, it makes sense! So here, `10` should be narrowed as `"10"` because there is "no information lost".

But C++ Primer objects to my understanding.

```cpp
vector<string> v5{"hi"}; // list initialization: v5 has one element
vector<string> v6("hi"); // error: can't construct a vector from a string literal
vector<string> v7{10};       // v7 has ten default-initialized elements
vector<string> v8{10, "hi"}; // v8 has ten elements with value "hi"
```

> "Although we used braces on all but one of these definitions, only `v5` is list initialized. In order to list initialize the `vector`, the values inside braces must match the element type. We cannot use an `int` to initialize a `string`, so the initializers for `v7` and `v8` can’t be element initializers. If list initialization isn’t possible, the compiler looks for other ways to initialize the object from the given values."

Now, I knew that it's wrong to simply think of `{}` initialization as list initialization. But my question is: why was C++ designed in this way? To me, considering we already have direct initialization in the form of  `vector<string> v8(10, "hi")`, it is regurgitating and confusing to make `vector<string> v8{10, "hi"}` as a "grammar sugar" to the `()` initialization.

Comment: Book off an hour of your life and watch [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) for an excellent rundown of how you can shoot yourself in the foot and how to avoid it.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think it's wrong. v7 is a vector of string, not int.

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fab43e0ad879873

Comment: For a while it was called uniform initialization. The idea was to have one syntax that did everything, and for the most part it works. Notable exception is the likes of `std::vector<int> five{5};` which uses the initializer list, so you get a `vector` with one value holding 5 and not a `vector` with five values all holding zero. For five zeroes you're stuck with `std::vector<int> five(5);`

Comment: @user4581301 did they change the name? I still call it uniform initialization

Comment: The answer to your question is answered in the video proposed by @user4581301 (6:10 - 8:03): https://youtu.be/7DTlWPgX6zs?t=370

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Thanks, I am still watching the video but I think it's time for me to take a break from C++. Not sure how long this break will be.

Comment: @Taekahn that probably depends on the They in question. I just don't see the term used as consistently as I had been seeing it. There was a spike up as the new name was pushed, but I'm not sure it stuck. At the very least we still need to know the dozen-or-so different types hiding behind the syntax. It did unify most of the syntax, and I consider that a good thing.

Comment: I'm using C++ for a long time (20 years or more). At all times, I wasn't aware of every feature (How could I?) but focused on a sub-set which helped me to get my work done. A really valuable invention (a landmark in my mind) were smart pointers which finally helped to keep projects alive (and stable) over a critical amount of source code. (Before I had some discontinued projects due to weird bugs I never was able to fix.) What I try you to tell: There was C++ before uniform initialization. You are not forced to use it whatever somebody else thinks. Just use what you feel able to master... ;-)